# Spring Scheduled tasks Doesnt kick with @ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

In my project i am using spring scheduler to invoke a certain process in a periodic interval, Using spring boot the application looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = {"com.included"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJms
public class myAlertsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
```

my scheduler method has an annotation:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${sometime:0}000", fixedDelayString = "${some time}000")
```

The problem surfaces when i introduce the component scan, and that is the scheduled method doesnt even gets invoked, however if i remove the component scan tag from the application above the method gets invoked as expected.
The component scan is scanning a package in one of the included jars through pom dependency which i am sure should not be a problem.

Comment: Try `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.yourpkg", "com.included"})` and remove `@ComponentScan`

Comment: No luck the package is scanned but the scheduler doesnt kick

Comment: Could you check via actuator `/bean` that the scheduler bean is indeed picked up ([reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html))

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, potentially suggesting a possible solution:

First, as suggested above, check that the scheduler bean is not getting registered by Spring using the actuator endpoint `/actuator/scheduledtasks`.

Assuming it isn't registered, it is possible that either your code or one of your dependencies defines a `@Configuration` bean with injected dependencies that eventually lead to your bean (which contains the `@Scheduled` annotation).

**A concrete scenario for example, learned the hard way:**

Let's assume the following Configuration bean:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.included"})
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    ClassA object;
    ...
}


public class ClassB {

    @Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${sometime:0}000", fixedDelayString = "${some time}000")
    public void scheduledMethod(){
     ...
    }
}
```

*If there is a dependency chain between `object` and your bean with the `@Scheduled` method (`ClassB`, potentially could be directly `ClassA`), the scheduler registration will not succeed.*

**Back to the Spring Bean Lifecycle**

When the Application Context is refreshed (after finished intialization), `BeanPostProcessors` that intercept bean creation are registered.

In our example the `@EnableAsync` annotation triggers the creation of a `AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. Through this post processor bean creation, our `ConfigClass` gets instantiated, and by proxy - ClassA and eventually the bean that contains the `@Scheduled` method.

Although the `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` will get created as well, `ClassB` has already been instantiated at this point, ***however the scheduled method will not register a scheduled task*** - since `BeanPostProcessor`s are registered to the bean factory only after this chain of creation.

Eventually the `BeanPostProcessorChecker` will get invoked once `ClassB` has been initialized (within `applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization`), warning us that:

`Bean ... of type [...] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors ...`

**Conclusion**

Adding injected dependencies inside Configuration beans has a potentially hazardous outcome.